# Python - permutation and percentage

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to calculate percentage change in values from 1-c1 to 4 for each `bench`. 
the values for each `bench` are in a `pythonic list` similar to `lists = [[],[],[],[],[],[]]`

Is there a library or any statistical package in python that can help me do this with ease?

```
"bench" "1-c1", "1-c3", "1-c6", "1-c7", "1-poll", "1", "2-c1", "2-c3", "2-c6", "2-c7", "2-poll", "2", "3-c1", "3-c3", "3-c6", "3-c7", "3-poll", "3", "4-c1", "4-c3", "4-c6", "4-c7", "4-poll", "4"
    a      1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12      13      14      15      16      17      18      19      20      21      22      23      24
    b      1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12      13      14      15      16      17      18      19      20      21      22      23      24
    c      1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12      13      14      15      16      17      18      19      20      21      22      23      24
    d      1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12      13      14      15      16      17      18      19      20      21      22      23      24
    e      1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12      13      14      15      16      17      18      19      20      21      22      23      24
    f      1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12      13      14      15      16      17      18      19      20      21      22      23      24
```

pls. let me know if something is not clear

```
lists = [
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
]
```

That's how the list looks like

Paulo, in response to your comment, the I want the % changes from `lists[0][0] to lists[n][n]`

Thanks to `Paulo`. I could improve my solution

```
listi = []
iter = []
percentage = [[],[],[],[],[]]
def increase_decrease(lists):
        for data in range(0,len(lists)):
                listi.append(lists[data][0])
        for row in listi:
                iterations = list(itertools.product(row,row))
                iter.append(iterations)
        for b in range(0, len(iter)):
                for a in range(0, len(iter[0])):
                        if (iter[b][a][0] != iter[b][a][1]) and (iter[b][a][0] > iter[b][a][1]):
                                percentage[b].append(float(float(float(iter[b][a][0] - iter[b][a][1])/iter[b][a][0]))*100)
                        if (iter[b][a][0] != iter[b][a][1]) and (iter[b][a][0] < iter[b][a][1]):
                                percentage[b].append(float(float(float(iter[b][a][1] - iter[b][a][0])/iter[b][a][1]))*100)
                print percentage[b]
```

Any other changes would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is that data in a file? Strange file format if so. It looks like the headers are comma delimited but the data is some kind of fixed width.

Comment: Everything is comma separated. I just wrote it that way so that is easy to understand.

Comment: Your second paragraph is not clear. What is "from... from ... and ... and ..."? If you use "from ... to ..." it will be easier to understand.

Comment: You could just google stats packages and look at their feature list.

Comment: I did look at Panda and numpy. But they don't seem to be offering this feature.
@PauloAlmeida: Improved the question.

Comment: To clarify - what would be some example output?

Comment: Updated my question with the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in comments, it would be helpful to have example output, but since you seem to only want a tool, and then implement it yourself, I think what you're looking for is `itertools.product`, which will give you all the permutations you need:

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

>>> for row in a:
...     print list(itertools.product(row, row))

[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
[(4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6)]
[(7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9), (8, 7), (8, 8), (8, 9), (9, 7), (9, 8), (9, 9)]
```

Then you can iterate through each generator returned by `itertools.product` and calculate the percentages, possibly skipping those where the index of the second value is equal or greater than that of the first (for instance, for the top row returned by `product`, you may only want (1, 2), (1, 3) and (2, 3)). This is how you might skip the redundant positions:

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

row = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
grouped = grouper(3, row)

for i, row in enumerate(grouped):
    for j, column in enumerate(row):
        if i < j:
            print column
```

The grouper function is [a recipe in the itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes).

Comment: Updated my question with the answer

Comment: I am not able to get only `(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)`. I tried to use list.index()

Comment: `itertools.combinations(row,2)` does the job :)

Comment: @pistal, Cool, I was in the process of adding a suggestion based on itertools too :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear about what the output should be exactly, but if you want to compare the `1-c1` values of `a` and `b`, then the `1-c1` values for `b` and `c`, etc. for each of the columns in your list you could do:

```
# NOTE: I'm using foo as input because it should have more interesting
# results than for your given list
foo = [[x for x in range(1, 11)], 
       [x for x in range(10, 0, -1)], 
       [x for x in range(1, 11)]]

ans = []
for comp, to in zip(foo[:-1], foo[1:]):
    ans.append([])
    for n in range(len(comp)):
        ans[-1].append((100 * to[n]/float(comp[n])) - 100)
```

The values stored in `ans` are:

```
[[900.0, 350.0, 166.66666666666669, 75.0, 20.0, -16.66666666666667, -42.857142857142854, -62.5, -77.77777777777777, -90.0],
 [-90.0, -77.77777777777777, -62.5, -42.857142857142854, -16.66666666666667, 20.0, 75.0, 166.66666666666669, 350.0, 900.0]]
```

So the first element in `ans` is a list containing the percent change between each respective element in the first and second lists in `foo`, and the second list is the same thing for the second and third lists in `foo`.

I hope this is what you are looking for!

---

**UPDATE:** So after working on something else for a bit, I got the idea that you want to compare each element to every other element in the entire matrix.

```
import itertools
from string import ascii_lowercase

# I converted the list into a dictionary so that the output would
# have better names than: Comparing 101 to 131 etc.
# The principle is the same for lists though
foo = {'BENCH-1': dict((l, x) for l, x in zip(ascii_lowercase, range(100, 103))),
       'BENCH-2': dict((l, x) for l, x in zip(ascii_lowercase, range(120, 117, -1))),
       'BENCH-3': dict((l, x) for l, x in zip(ascii_lowercase, range(130, 133)))}

# Find all combinations of the benches
for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in itertools.combinations(foo.iteritems(), 2):
    # Find all pairs in each of the combinations of the benches.
    # NOTE: the sorted is to help the readability of the output
    # NOTE: ik1 = inner key 1, iv2 = inner value 2
    for (ik1, iv1), (ik2, iv2) in sorted(itertools.product(v1.iteritems(), v2.iteritems())):
        print 'Comparing %s to %s: %f' % (k1 + ik1, k2 + ik2, (100 * iv1 / float(iv2)) - 100)
```

The output is:

```
Comparing BENCH-2a to BENCH-3a: -7.69230769231
Comparing BENCH-2a to BENCH-3b: -8.39694656489
Comparing BENCH-2a to BENCH-3c: -9.09090909091
Comparing BENCH-2b to BENCH-3a: -8.46153846154
Comparing BENCH-2b to BENCH-3b: -9.16030534351
Comparing BENCH-2b to BENCH-3c: -9.84848484848
Comparing BENCH-2c to BENCH-3a: -9.23076923077
Comparing BENCH-2c to BENCH-3b: -9.92366412214
Comparing BENCH-2c to BENCH-3c: -10.6060606061
Comparing BENCH-2a to BENCH-1a: 20.0
Comparing BENCH-2a to BENCH-1b: 18.8118811881
Comparing BENCH-2a to BENCH-1c: 17.6470588235
Comparing BENCH-2b to BENCH-1a: 19.0
Comparing BENCH-2b to BENCH-1b: 17.8217821782
Comparing BENCH-2b to BENCH-1c: 16.6666666667
Comparing BENCH-2c to BENCH-1a: 18.0
Comparing BENCH-2c to BENCH-1b: 16.8316831683
Comparing BENCH-2c to BENCH-1c: 15.6862745098
Comparing BENCH-3a to BENCH-1a: 30.0
Comparing BENCH-3a to BENCH-1b: 28.7128712871
Comparing BENCH-3a to BENCH-1c: 27.4509803922
Comparing BENCH-3b to BENCH-1a: 31.0
Comparing BENCH-3b to BENCH-1b: 29.702970297
Comparing BENCH-3b to BENCH-1c: 28.431372549
Comparing BENCH-3c to BENCH-1a: 32.0
Comparing BENCH-3c to BENCH-1b: 30.6930693069
Comparing BENCH-3c to BENCH-1c: 29.4117647059
```

To do this with a list as input:

```
import itertools
for b1, b2 in itertools.combinations(foo, 2):
    for v1, v2 in sorted(itertools.product(b1, b2)):
        print (100 * v1 / float(v2)) - 100)
```